# Auto Hotkey Convert any copied files, HTML, or other formatted text to plain text

Tags: autohotkey

Auto hotkey command to convert clipboard from any copied files to plain text is not working.

Supposedly after copying something to the clipboard, all I have to do is run the following command in the script:

```
clipboard = %clipboard%   ;
```

followed by (not necessarily):

```
ClipWait ;
```

Which waits until there is text in the clipboard.

But my script just never manages to convert the copied data into plain text, and the wait will just stay on forever. Also, I do have something copied into the clipboard, it is codelines of a step7 plc program, but I really don t know how step 7 formats them in the clipboard. All I want is to get the data somehow into text, I know it can be done somehow (although maybe not with auto-hotkey) :(

Comment: Do you mean you select a file in Explorer and want to store the text contents of the selecting text file into clipboard?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use clipwait *before* you use that trick.  Another option is to check periodically  for a path in the clipboard.  If you don't do some kind of verification, you will lose the ability to copy binary data (e.g., pictures from websites).

This includes a *basic* check for the `:\` appearing in the clipboard (e.g. `C:\abc\def`).

```
Loop
{
    ClipWait
    IfInString, Clipboard, :\
        Clipboard = %Clipboard%
}
```